# Invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' and error in passing argument 1

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I have written the solution of a C++ problem which should show an ordered array with values from a matrix. I have done it, but it keeps showing two errors and I can't figure out how to solve them.

**The errors are:**

Line 84|error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'int*'|

Line 57|error: in passing argument 1 of 'void Inserare(int&, int*, int)'|

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void CitireMatrice(int& n,int mat[100][100])
{
    int i,j,m;
    cout<<"Da n ";
    cin>>n;
    m=n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Matricea["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]=";
            cin>>mat[i][j];
        }
}

void Tiparire(int n,int X[])
{   int i;
    if(n!=0)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            cout<<X[i]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Sirul este vid";
}

int Prim(int n)
{
    int div=2;
    while(div<=sqrt(n) && n%div!=0)
    {
        if(div == 2)
            div = 3;
        else
            div = div + 2;
    }
    return div;
}

int SuperPrim(int n)
{
    while(n!=0)
    {
        if(Prim(n)==0)
            return 0;
        n=n/10;
    }
    return 1;

}

void Inserare(int& n,int X[],int v)
{   int i;
    int p=1; //prima pozitie
    while(X[p]>v && p<=n)
        p++;
    for(i=n;i>=p;i++)
        X[i+1]=X[i];
    X[p]=v;
    n++;
}

int Apartine(int X[],int n,int v)
{   int i;
    int gasit=0; //initializat cu 0 deoarece nu a gasit nimic inca
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        if(X[i]==v)
            gasit=1;
    return gasit;
}

void Construire(int n,int mat[100][100],int X[],int& k)
{   int i,j;
    k=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            if((i>j && i+j<n+1) || (i<j && i+j>n+1)) //daca apartine triunghiului drept SAU strang
               if(SuperPrim(mat[i][j])==1 && Apartine(X,k,mat[i][j])==0)
                    Inserare(X,k,mat[i][j]);
}



int main()
{
    int m,n,mat[100][100],X[100],k;
    CitireMatrice(n,mat);
    Construire(n,mat,X,k);
    Tiparire(n,X);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int X[]` doesn't form a valid `int` lvalue when specifying `X` as parameter. It actually decays to a `int*`

Comment: int& n or int &n means the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Inserare(X,k,mat[i][j]);
```

X is table address and according to declaration
    void Inserare(int& n,int X[],int v)
you should pass reference. maybe you wanted to switch X and k in your call?

Comment: I mean that MAYBE you used arguments in the wrong order. You used:
    Inserare(X,k,mat[i][j])
and according to function declaration, it COULD be ok, if you used"
    Inserare(k,X,mat[i][j]);
You used X as a first argument - it is an address of the first element of an array - it doesn't match reference (1st argument in declaration). That is the error in your program. Best :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the function `void Inserare(int& n,int X[],int v)`, and you try to call `Inserare(X,k,mat[i][j]);`.

You are probably trying to send the parameters in the wrong order.  Try to change your call on `Inserare(k,X,mat[i][j]);`